# Entropy change for an irreversible process

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, adiabatic

I have been stuck for hours now on this thing. While going through my thermodynamic lectures, I came across this: 'The entropy change for the system for an adiabatic irreversible process is always positive while that of the surroundings doesn't change.'
Will someone please explain how that is true.

PS: I'm not quite used to seeing devilish expressions in thermodynamics yet.

Comment: can you imagine a mechanical system *with* friction such that while your forces are overcoming the internal friction the system *cools*?

Comment: @hyportnex How can the system cool if it is adiabatic?  Also, what about an adiabatic system in which no mechanical processes are present, like one that is initially at an non-uniform temperature and which then thermally equilibrates.  That would certainly qualify as an irreversible adiabatic process.

Comment: @Chet_Miller You are completely right but I am just trying to give a physically intuitive hint regarding the meaning of Joule's experiment to somebody who says "I'm not quite used to seeing devilish expressions in thermodynamics yet".

Answer (score 5):

In an adiabatic irreversible process, entropy is generated within the system, and there is no transfer of entropy to the surroundings because heat cannot flow out.  Thermally, the surroundings do not even know that anything has happened within the system.  So all the generated entropy remains within the system and causes the system entropy to rise, while the entropy of the surroundings does not change.

Answer (score 3):

The only way the entropy of the surroundings can change is if there is heat transfer to or from the surroundings. An adiabatic process is, by definition, a process in which there is no heat transfer between the system and its surroundings. So it is impossible for the entropy of the surroundings to change for an adiabatic process.

For a *reversible* adiabatic process the entropy of the system also does not change. An example of a reversible adiabatic process is the very slow (quasi-static) expansion or compression of a gas by a piston in an insulated cylinder such that the gas pressure is always in equilibrium with the external pressure. We call this reversible work.

For an *irreversible* adiabatic process entropy is generated within the system resulting in an increase in the entropy of the system only. An example of an irreversible adiabatic process is the rapid expansion or compression of a gas by a piston in an insulated cylinder such that the gas is not in internal equilibrium during the process. We call this irreversible work.

Hope this helps.